# jqGrid afterSaveCell uses incorrect rowId on filtered grid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

So I have a grid with say 2 rows in it.

```
slappy, 1, 10, 100
happy, 2, 20, 200
```

I then filter on the grid and reduce the list to just 1 row

```
happy, 2, 20, 200
```

The original row 1 is **not** in the filtered list.

I change "happy" to "pappy" and remove the filter.  I now have;

```
pappy, 1, 10, 100
happy, 2, 20, 200
```

So it changed row 1 column 1 because within the `afterSaveCell` method, the returned `rowId` was `1` and not `2`.  So my code of;

```
afterSaveCell: function (rowid, cellname, value, iRow, iCol) {
    alert(rowid + ":" + iRow);
    GRID.GridData[iRow - 1][iCol - 1] = value;
},
```

will always fail because it's changing the data for the wrong row.

What is the method for making edits on filtered lists work?

Comment: I'm almost sure that you don't filled correctly the input data of the grid. You should include `datatype`, `colModel`, `loadonce`, `jsonReader` parameters which you use. Additionally the input data for the grid (the two rows of data) would be important to know. I suppose that the input data don't contains any `id` (rowid) information and so jqGrid have to assign ids 1,2,3,.. on every filling of the grid page (on every page, on filtered page of data too).

Answer (score 0):

jqGrid don't provide you any interface to edit `id` attribute of the row even if you define `key: true` in a column and the column is editable. On the other side you can easy adjust `id` attribute yourself if the column which holds the id will be modified. For example

```
afterSaveCell: function (rowid, cellname, value, iRow, iCol) {
    if (iCol === iMyKeyColumn) { // iMyKeyColumn is the column which should be
                                 // sync with rowid
        // adjust id attribute with new id value
        $(this.rows[iRow]).attr("id", value); // if you use idPrefix you should add
                                              // it to value: this.p.idPrefix + value
    }
}
```

In general it's not good to allow the user to modify id values because id have to be unique over the HTML page and the user typically don't think about the problem of id duplicates.